# Formatar data com DatePipe Angular

Tags: typescript, angular

Eu tenho uma data no formato timestamp e queria formatar para texto em português, por exemplo: "Quarta-feira, 18 de Outubro, 2017", mas eu ponho o pipe "| date:'fullDate'" e não funciona. Quando eu tiro o `toLocaleString("pt-BR")` e retorno um Date na função ele me retorna "Wednesday, October 18, 2017". Obrigado de antemão!

typescript

```
public dt: Date = new Date();
public getDate(): string {
  return this.dt.toLocaleString("pt-BR");
}
```

html

```
<div class="data"><b>{{getDate() | date:'fullDate'}}</b></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe um projeto que já possui um conjunto de funções destinadas a trabalhar com Data, pode dar uma conferida em:

http://momentjs.com/

Mas, segue também uma alternativa:

```
$scope.getDate = function() {
    let dt = new Date();

    let month = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'];
    let week  = ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado'];

    let semana = week[dt.getDay()];
    let mes = month[dt.getMonth()];

    return semana + ', ' + dt.getDate() + ' de ' + mes + ', ' + dt.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: Resolveu! Muito obrigado!